# how to write a correct request (httr::GET or httr::POST)

Tags: r, post, get, httr

I would like to extract the `links` listed under "Information" on a webpage using `R`. The data is publicly available and scraping is not prohibitet.

With an empty search on https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/mep/#/ and >export results I get a CSV. However, this CSV does not include what I need (links under "Information"). I thought that I could use this CSV (with unique identifiers, e.g., `Vk_20220224_16`) to programmatically open the pages separately (e.g., https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/mep/#/?q=Vk_20220224_16) and then extract these links (with a function using `html_attr("href")` etc.).

Unfortunately, I fail to get the content of the separate pages.
I get an error message (400 Bad Request) when I use `httr:GET(url)`.

I think I get this error message because my request does not include all parameter that the server needs. Is there a way to check which parameter are needed so that the server understands my request?

Example:

```r
#library
library(httr)

# read html
html <- GET("https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/mep/#/?q=Vk_20220224_16")
html
#> Response [https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/mep/#/?q=Vk_20220224_16]
#>   Date: 2022-12-22 23:13
#>   Status: 400
#>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
#>   Size: 347 B
#> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
#> <html><head>
#> <title>400 Bad Request</title>
#> </head><body>
#> <h1>Bad Request</h1>
#> <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
#> </p>
#> <p>Additionally, a 400 Bad Request
#> error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the requ...
#> </body></html>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Update**

I just learned that I can check the parameter needed using firefox:
[image]

So I tried using `httr::POST` but I still do not get the page content/table, I only get `"Loading..."`

```r
#library
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(rvest)


# set parameter
body <- list(
  queryTerm="Vk_20220224_16",
  fromDate="",
  toDate="")

# POST
res <- POST(
       "https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/",
       body = jsonlite::toJSON(body),
       encode = "form",
       verbose()
       )

# get results
read_html(res)
#> {html_document}
#> <html>
#> [1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 ...
#> [2] <body>\n<mep-app>Loading...</mep-app><script type="text/javascript" src=" ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: If the site is set up for http requests then you would refer to the site's API documentation.

Comment: @Abigail thank you. how do I know if the site is set up for http requests? I could not find a API documentation for swissmedic.ch

Comment: My guess would be it's not. You could look into scraping the page, I know `rvest` is a main package for that but I haven't used it.

Comment: In my experience, if a website _wants_ you to use its API, it clearly communicates it on the pages that allow (e.g.) filtering/selection of data. If a website wants to to _not_ scrape its data, it often has a terms-of-use or similar that is clear in its legalese (which means not always very clear) that scraping/extraction of its data is not allowed without explicit written permission. For all other websites, `rvest` is perfectly (and legally) well-suited.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you. Swissmedic does not forbid to scrape this conent (there is no terms of use, robots.txt or any other information that suggests that it would not be allowed). The content is publicly available. Isnt `rvest` just a wrapper for `httr`?

Comment: No, it is far more than a wrapper: it provides the concept of "session", where after your first call (perhaps to log in), all subsequent calls can use this (think: cookies and continuation of presence). You can use this "session" to jump to different pages within the "browser session", and many things that a simple `httr::GET` does _not_ cover are handled fluently. I suggest you look into it, possibly again, and look at its [docs](https://rvest.tidyverse.org/). It handles many many many things where a simple `GET` does not work.

Comment: FYI, `res <- httr::POST("https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/mep/api/publications/search?pageNumber=0&sortingProperty=PUBLICATION_DATE&direction=DESC", body=list(queryTerm="Vk_20220224_16", fromDate=NA, toDate=NA, onlyUpdates=FALSE))` returns `list(correlationId = "c367d34d-8f0d-41e7-aa07-f36c8352ed95", exceptionName = "HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException", exceptionMessage = NULL, content = NULL, stackTrace = NULL)`, not sure if that's more meaningful.

Comment: I see. thank you. Just an update, there are [terms of use](https://www.swissmedic.ch/swissmedic/en/home/conditions.html). They state that the content is publicly available and that downloads are allowed.

Comment: But there is no robots.txt file. However, webscraping is generally allowed in Switzerland.

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of the returned list above.

Comment: @r2evans I get your point with `rvest`. However, in my case, swissmedic allows to download a .csv with unique identifier (e.g., `Vk_20220224_16`), unfortunately this .csv does not include the links. Therefore I thought I could elude a cumbersome `rvest` solution with sessions and jumping to different pages.

Comment: I see no offering of CSV formats on the page, just PDFs and "Export results" (which in this case only has 3 rows of data). Is that what you need?

Comment: @r2evans With an empty search on https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/mep/#/ and >export results I get a CSV. However, this CSV does not include what I need (links under "Information"). I thought that I could use this CSV to programmatically open the pages separately (e.g., https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/mep/#/?q=Vk_20220224_16) and then extract these links (with a function using `html_attr("href")` etc.). But I fail to get the content of the separate pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to request with `httr2`

```
library(httr2)
library(tidyverse)

"https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/mep/api/publications/search?pageNumber=0&sortingProperty=PUBLICATION_DATE&direction=DESC" %>%
  request() %>%
  req_body_json(
    list(
      fromDate = "2022-12-04",
      toDate = "2022-12-20",
      queryTerm = NULL,
      onlyUpdates = "false"
    )
  ) %>%
  req_perform() %>%
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = T) %>%
  pluck("content") %>%
  as_tibble()

# A tibble: 37 × 9
   publikationsDatum swissmedicRef  hersteller                status status…¹ begru…² devices freig…³ docum…⁴
   <chr>             <chr>          <chr>                     <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <list>  <lgl>   <list> 
 1 2022-12-07        Vk_20221202_03 Medtronic CoreValve LLC   UPDATE 2022-12… "Added… <df>    TRUE    <df>   
 2 2022-12-20        Vk_20221216_12 Biocartis NV              UPDATE 2022-12… "Added… <df>    TRUE    <df>   
 3 2022-12-20        Vk_20221219_01 Siemens Healthcare GmbH   FIRST  2022-12… ""      <df>    TRUE    <df>   
 4 2022-12-20        Vk_20221216_19 Medicvent AB              FIRST  2022-12… ""      <df>    TRUE    <df>   
 5 2022-12-20        Vk_20221213_25 Macopharma                FIRST  2022-12… ""      <df>    TRUE    <df>   
 6 2022-12-20        Vk_20221208_26 Spiegelberg GmbH & Co. KG FIRST  2022-12… ""      <df>    TRUE    <df>   
 7 2022-12-06        Vk_20221201_21 Fujifilm Corporation      UPDATE 2022-12… "Rewor… <df>    TRUE    <df>   
 8 2022-12-20        Vk_20221216_15 Maquet Critical Care AB   FIRST  2022-12… ""      <df>    TRUE    <df>   
 9 2022-12-20        Vk_20221216_17 Siemens Healthcare GmbH   FIRST  2022-12… ""      <df>    TRUE    <df>   
10 2022-12-20        Vk_20221215_03 custo med GmbH            FIRST  2022-12… ""      <df>    TRUE    <df>   
# … with 27 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​statusDatum, ²​begruendung, ³​freigeschaltet,
#   ⁴​documents
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

With search parameter

```
"https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/mep/api/publications/search?pageNumber=0&sortingProperty=PUBLICATION_DATE&direction=DESC" %>%
  request() %>%
  req_body_json(list(
    fromDate = NULL,
    toDate = NULL,
    queryTerm = "Vk_20220224_16",
    onlyUpdates = "false"
  )) %>%
  req_perform() %>%
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>%
  pluck("content") %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  unnest(everything()) 

# A tibble: 3 × 16
  publikatio…¹ swiss…² herst…³ status statu…⁴ begru…⁵ hande…⁶ sn    lot   swVer…⁷ model besch…⁸ freig…⁹ title
  <chr>        <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <lgl>   <chr>
1 2022-03-07   Vk_202… Siemen… FIRST  2022-0… ""      Artis … ""    ""    ""      ""    MD: St… TRUE    DE-1 
2 2022-03-07   Vk_202… Siemen… FIRST  2022-0… ""      Artis Q ""    ""    ""      ""    MD: St… TRUE    FR-1 
3 2022-03-07   Vk_202… Siemen… FIRST  2022-0… ""      Artis … ""    ""    ""      ""    MD: St… TRUE    IT-1 
# … with 2 more variables: language <chr>, version <chr>, and abbreviated variable names ¹​publikationsDatum,
#   ²​swissmedicRef, ³​hersteller, ⁴​statusDatum, ⁵​begruendung, ⁶​handelsname, ⁷​swVersion, ⁸​beschreibungKlasse,
#   ⁹​freigeschaltet
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Download links of the documents, which can be looped/mapped to auto download:

```
str_c("https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/mep/api/publications/", "Vk_20220224_16", 
      "/documents/", 0:(number_of_documents - 1))  

[1] "https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/mep/api/publications/Vk_20220224_16/documents/0"
[2] "https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/mep/api/publications/Vk_20220224_16/documents/1"
[3] "https://fsca.swissmedic.ch/mep/api/publications/Vk_20220224_16/documents/2"
```

Comment: marvellous. where did you get `number_of_documents` in `str_c``?

Comment: Ah I see it is just the rownr of the tibble after the search with parameters.

Comment: @ava Oh yeah, I skipped a part - but you caught it!